# CKEditor inline link is empty

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, inline-editing

I have a problem with the CKEditor inline edit mode.

I have editable area with few links inside.

When I click the link button in the toolbar to change the link I do not see the current URL.
The field is empty and I cannot edit the href, only place a new one.

The editable page is inside an iframe (if that matters).

I haven't change almost anything in the cofing.
Here is my config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'format,richcombo,floatpanel,panel,listblock,autogrow';

    config.toolbar = [
    [ 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'BulletedList' ],
    [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ]
    ];

    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced;link:target';

    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6';

    config.extraAllowedContent = 'span;*[id](*){*}';

    config.title = false;
};

CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(e) {
    var dialogName = e.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = e.data.definition;
    var name = e.data.name;

    if (name === 'link') {
        dialogDefinition.minHeight = 30;

        // remove all except url
        var tabInfo = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        try { tabInfo.remove('linkType'); } catch(e) {}
        try { tabInfo.remove('anchorOptions'); } catch(e) {}
        try { tabInfo.remove('emailOptions'); } catch(e) {}
    }

    dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
        var top = parent.window.$(parent.document.body).scrollTop();

        this.move(this.getPosition().x,top);

        if (name === 'link') {
            document.querySelector('input.cke_dialog_ui_input_text').focus();
        }
    };
});
```

Part of my HTML:

```
<p data-editable="true" contenteditable="true"><a href="http://domain.com">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies veh icula ut id elitInt eger posuere.</a></p>
```

Comment: Remove the try-catch statements and most likely you'll see what goes wrong.

Comment: Without try/catch the result is the same.

Comment: I didn't say it will be different. I meant that you might see errors in the JS console which you might not see now. I assume you check the JS console.